# Prism 6 Popup Window with EventAggregator to replace a service

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, mvvm

I have a WPF project with `Prism 6` and `EF6`. In my project I have a `MainTabModule` which has four ViewModels. One of these `ViewModels` is called `ContactViewModel`.

The `MainTabModule` will initialize and resolve my `EF` context and will also resolve my services. Finally I register my views to the regions in the `Shell`. This means that all four ViewModels are always active during the entire lifetime of the application (this is intended).

Now comes the challenging part. I've created a custom popup notification class that can pass in an entity. In that popup I can modify the entity and return it. Seems simple enough, however that entity may have foreign keys. Which means I need some way to search for that new foreign entity.

As far as I know I can't dependency inject **my own services** into the `PopupViewModel`. But I can use the `EventAggregator`. So I created two events.

```
public class ContactSearchEvent : PubSubEvent<string>
{
}

public class ContactCollectionEvent : PubSubEvent<List<Contact>>
{
}
```

The ContactViewModel (which is already active, see the first a second paragraph) will subscribe to the `ContactSearchEvent` in the constructor.

```
    public ContactSearchViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ContactSearchEvent>().Subscribe(EventAggregatorSearch);
    }
```

Then `PopupViewModel` will subscribe to the `ContactCollectionEvent` in its constructor.

```
    public ContactSearchViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ContactCollectionEvent>().Subscribe(SetCollection);
    }
```

The user can now type in the string payload from the Popup Window and search.

```
    private void Search()
    {
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ContactSearchEvent>().Publish(SearchPayload);
    }
```

The `ContactSearchViewModel` will now receive the payload then publish to `ContactCollectionEvent`. Normally it would use the service to search the datbase.

```
    private void EventAggregatorSearch(string payload)
    {
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ContactCollectionEvent>().Publish(new List<Contact>
        {
            new Contact
            {
                FirstName = "Test1"
            },
            new Contact
            {
                FirstName = "Test2"
            },
            new Contact
            {
                FirstName = "Test3"
            }
        });
    }
```

Back in the `PopupViewModel` we can now set the collection to the property.

```
    private void SetCollection(List<Contact> contacts)
    {
        SearchResults = contacts;
    }
```

This process works. However, I feel like there may be a better way in order to use my services to search the database from a Popup Window in Prism 6. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can make it simpler or better?